# Adding an attribute to a nested map[string]interface{} in Golang

Tags: go

I am dealing with data that is of the type `map[string]interface{}`. it can have unlimited number of nested objects inside (map[string]interface{}) types.

**EDIT:** *This data comes from mongodb. I can't really apply golang's struct here because the attributes vary from document to document. All I want to do is get the most deeply nested object, add a new attribute to it and make sure the entire data object is updated after.*

```
data["person"] = map[string]interface{}{
    "peter": map[string]interface{}{
        "scores": map[string]interface{}{
            "calculus": 88,
            "algebra":  99,
            "golang":   89,
        },
    },
}
```

This data is coming from a remote API and I have no idea of the properties inside. All I want to add is add new attribute inside the last object (in this case "scores"), and lets say with this new attribute ("physics") the data would look like this

```
data["person"] = map[string]interface{}{
    "peter": map[string]interface{}{
        "scores": map[string]interface{}{
            "calculus": 88,
            "algebra":  99,
            "golang":   89,
            "physics":  95,
        },
    },
}
```

I am not sure how I could get that attribute added to the very last object.

I did recursive type checking and was able to get each field and print its value. But because maps are not referential I cannot add a value to the original map when I reach the map with the values that are not complex types.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    data["person"] = map[string]interface{}{
        "peter": map[string]interface{}{
            "scores": map[string]interface{}{
                "calculus": 88,
                "algebra":  99,
                "golang":   89,
            },
        },
    }

    parseMap(data)
}


func parseMap(aMap map[string]interface{}) interface{} {
    var retVal interface{}

    for _, val := range aMap {
        switch val.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            retVal = parseMap(val.(map[string]interface{}))
        //case []interface{}:
        //  retVal = parseArray(val.([]interface{}))
        default:
            //here i would have done aMap["physics"] = 95 if I could access the original map by reference, but that is not possible

            retVal = aMap

        }
    }

    return retVal
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you tried so far.  Describe the logic for finding the "last object".  Is it the last object in lexicographic key order, most deeply nested object or something else?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Describe the logic for finding the "last object".  Your intent is not clear from the code and prose.  The code attempts to add a value to a map containing a value that is not a map[string]interface{} or []interface{}.  The prose says to add the value to a map that does not have complex values.

Comment: ok the above code just checks the type of each attribute. all i am interested in is adding a new attribute to the last nested map. and that seems not to be possible when you dont know the names of your attributes ahead of time.

Comment: Describe "last".  Is it last in breadth first order, depth first order, most deeply nested or ????.   How are keys ordered?

Comment: most deeply nested. the data is a mongo response. there is not structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the comments on the question, the goal is to set a value in the most deeply nested map.

Use the following function to find a map at the greatest nesting level. If there is more than one map at the greatest nesting level, this function returns an arbitrary one of those maps.

```
func findDeepest(m map[string]interface{}) (int, map[string]interface{}) {
    depth := 0
    candidate := m
    for _, v := range m {
        if v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            d, c := findDeepest(v)
            if d+1 > depth {
                depth = d + 1
                candidate = c
            }
        }
    }
    return depth, candidate
}
```

Use it like this to set a value in the deeply nested map:

```
_, m := findDeepest(data)
m["physics"] = 95
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XiEz-XktwyP).

Comment: Thanks Cerise Limon!

Comment: Why do you need the `depth` variable though? It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: The depth variable is used to select the deepest map contained in any child map. This variable is not needed with the sample data because there's at most one nested map at each level.

Comment: ok, i get it. thanks. wondering, what happens when there are sibling objects at same level.

Comment: @pro  If there is more than one map at the greatest nesting level, this function returns arbitrary one of those maps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid working with the raw `map[string]interface{}` type as much as you can.  The Go `encoding/json` file can deal with string-keyed maps just fine, and hopefully the remote API has *some* sort of specification for what you're dealing with.  (You know that you're expecting a `person` top-level key and `scores` in a specific point in the hierarchy, for example.)

I'm assuming the remote API is JSON-over-HTTP.  You might model its structure as

```
type Input struct {
    Person map[string]Person `json:"person"`
}

type Person struct {
    Scores map[string]int `json:"scores"`
}
```

Once you've `json.Unmarshal()`ed data into this structure, you can directly set

```
data.Person["peter"].Scores["physics"] = 95
```

and then `json.Marshal()` the result again.  https://play.golang.org/p/qoAVFodSvK2 has a complete example.

If you really wanted to directly manipulate the `map[string]interface{}` structure, I'd suggest splitting each "level" into a separate function call

```
func ParseTopLevel(data map[string]interface{}) {
    switch peter := data["peter"].(type) {
    case map[string]interface{}:
        ParsePeter(peter)
    }
}
```

`map` types are [passed by reference](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action), so when you get to the bottom of the stack you can directly set `scores["physics"] = 95`.  (In your original code, I'd be surprised if you can't directly set `aMap["physics"]` as you propose, though it's rather imprecise on what gets set; compare https://play.golang.org/p/VuTjcjezwwU.)

Comment: I can't really apply structs here because the data is a mongo document and i don't know ahead of time what attributes it has.